# Chrome Extensions: How to Manage separate instances of background pages?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Does anyone know of a way to get each `separate Chrome Window` to run a `different background page instance`?

Currently, my problem is that I need to open two chrome windows and have each background page be its own separate instance. This "mimics" the act of two separate users using the extension on their own computer. Doing this will allow me to test the extension as `two different people` yet on `one computer`. Right now, when I open two Chrome Windows, it uses the one background page instance (as I suppose it should).

I guess any acceptable method would be great, whether that is some form of multiple Chrome `sign-ins` or installing `different instances` of chrome. The best solution however would be code based, in the realm of the actual Chrome Extension API, if it allows.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add the true reason for wanting two different background instances? This looks like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to, perhaps there's a better method than using two different instances (which is possible and quite easy to do though).

Comment: The middle paragraph explains the exact reason why I need two different instances. Usually `background pages` exist once for all chrome windows. I can't mimic people on two different computers if both "people" (in this case, me) are connected to the same background page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time I solved my problem fairly easily. It requires you to have `two Google accounts`. So if you do not have two accounts and do not want two accounts, it may be best to use `Rob W's answer` on this post...

Steps:

- Open up a Chrome window.
- Click the settings drop down -> then click settings
- Under the `Users` heading, click `add new user`
- You may be prompted to sign in using a Google account, do so
- Open up a second window, repeat process and assign the second user to the current window
- Now you should have two windows, under two different users. Both use their own settings and their own extensions, along with their own `background pages`.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to have two instances of a background page is to enable split incognito behaviour, and open an incognito window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>).

To enable split incognito mode, add the following to your manifest file:

```
"split": "incognito"
```

If you really want to simulate two or more users, use different data directories, by starting Chrome with the `--user-data-dir` flag. For example:

```
chromium --user-data-dir=/tmp/whatever/
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually solved it myself in a somewhat easier way but it requires two google accounts, this method seems to be best if you were not able to have two google accounts.

Comment: The method at the bottom of my answer is similar to your method, except that you don't have to sign up with any Google account. Because it doesn't require any sign-up, you can get up and running within a few seconds. I usually also use the `--load-extension=path/to/exrensionfolder` to load my extension being developed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could instantiate some "background page object" in the one background page for each open window? Put all your functionality in that class and create some array with all the instances in it.

Just some brainstorming, hope it gets you somewhere.